# ¿En un elemento vacío es necesario poner la diagonal?

Tags: html, html5

esque veo a mucha gente que utiliza el salto de linea de la sig. manera:

`</br>`

pero también he visto que lo utilizan de la sig manera:

`<br>`

¿Segun la W3C , cual es la forma correcta de escribirlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la especificación de la W3C, localizada aquí [espec.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/syntax.html)

A estos elementos se les llama `void elements` y no deben tener contenido bajo ninguna circunstancia, es decir

Esto es válido

```
<br id="elemento">
```

Pero esto no es válido

```
<br <p>elemento p</p>>
```

Sin embargo no existe como tal en la documentación un apartado que para estos elementos indique como obligatorio el uso de la `/` para cerrar estas etiquetas.

Sin embargo debes tener presente que vas a encontrar mucha información, que indica que dentro de la especificación de `XHTML` previa a HTML5 estaba basada en `XML` que como sabemos tiene una estructura similar a lo sighuiente

```
<caja> 
        <name>Yo mismo</name> 
</caja>
```

Donde como puedes ver el cierre de todas las etiquetas es necesario, sin embargo si nos basamos en la especificación que te compartí arriba no lo marca como punto necesario

De hecho la misma documentación, indica lo siguiente y cito

> Optionally, a "/" character, which may be present only if the element is a void element.

Lo cual lo podemos traducir como:

Opcionalmente, un caracter "/", el cual puede estar presente solamente si el elemento es un *elemento void*

Lo anterior por que los elementos `void` solo tienen la etiqueta de inicio y carecen de la etiqueta final

Es decir

Esto es válido

```
<br />
```

Y esto también lo es

```
<br>
```

Comment: ¿Pero al utilizar "/" no importa si lo pongo a principio del texto o al final de una etiqueta vacia?

Comment: checa lo que pondré como actualización para responderte @OscarIvanLopez

Comment: yo me referia que poner </br>  tanto como <br/> .¿Da igual de la dos formas? @shadow

Comment: no amigo, dentro del específicación, también indica que si pones `/` en todo caso va al final @OscarIvanLopez

Comment: @OscarIvanLopez por eso te coloqué los ejemplos de lo que sería válido o no al usar dichas tags

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda bro ^<^